# A little puzzle for you

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

### XXXX XXXXX

### &

**GRY (12)** ➡️ - - - - - -

**TIE (35)** ➡️ - - - - - -

**IL (3)** ➡️ - - - - - -

**LA (14)** ➡️ - - - - -

**SH (3)** ➡️ - - - - - - -

**IS (14)** ➡️ - - -

**FO (34)** ➡️ - - - - -

### What six-word phrase am I looking for?

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concealed six-word phrase is:

> **Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs**

While the nine 'X's in the opening line represent the first two words here, the rest of the puzzle is supposed to be inferred as follows...

> Note first that there are **seven** lines to the rest of the puzzle. Each one clues a word which represents a **characteristic** of one of Disney's '[Seven Dwarfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Dwarfs)'. To show by example...
>
>  The first one clues the word **AN**GRY. What we do here is take the given letters and insert spaces in the positions given by the numbers in the parentheses, so 'GRY (12)' becomes '..GRY'. We then need to fill those spaces to come up with a synonym for a characteristic of one of the Seven Dwarfs. The name of the Dwarf in question can then be derived - in this case, **ANGRY** leads us to **GRUMPY**.

Doing this for all seven lines yields the following:

> GRY (12) ➡️ ..GRY ➡️ **AN**GRY ➡️ GRUMPY
>  TIE (35) ➡️ TI.E. ➡️ TI**R**E**D** ➡️ SLEEPY
>  IL (3) ➡️ IL. ➡️ IL**L** ➡️ SNEEZY
>  LA (14) ➡️ .LA. ➡️ **G**LA**D** ➡️ HAPPY
>  SH (3) ➡️ SH. ➡️ SH**Y** ➡️ BASHFUL
>  IS (14) ➡️ .IS. ➡️ **W**IS**E** ➡️ DOC
>  FO (34) ➡️ FO.. ➡️ FO**OL** ➡️ DOPEY

This also makes sense of the title...

> Specifically, its reference to this being a *little* puzzle for us, when it involves these characters renowned for being of below-average height!